# Setting minDate/maxDate dynamically on html datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a situation in which I have fromDt and toDt dates and i want to adjust their min and max dynamically. e.g. max of fromDt should be min of toDt or min of toDt should be max of fromDt

However, this is not working using Angular JS ng-min and ng-max. It just shows all date range. Hardcoding max and min works as expected, but I want to use ng-min/min/ng-max/max to be adjusted dynamically. Any feedback from experts would be greatly helpful

```
<input type="month" ng-model="fromDt"  id="fromDt" ng-min="2015-01" ng-max="{{toDt}}" ng-change="fetch(fromDt, toDt)">              
 
<input type="month" ng-model="toDt"  id="toDt" ng-min="{{fromDt}}" ng-change="fetch(fromDt, toDt)" >
```

Comment: Binding `ng-min` & `ng-max` does not change the `min` or `max` attribute values. So the visualization continues to show the entire range. These two only are used for Angular's form validation. You'll have to set `min` and `max` in order to constrain the date picker.

Comment: Thank you for reply.

We are trying to use 2 date pickers to allow the users to select a range. So we want the first datepicker's max value to be the value of the second datepicker and the second datepicker's min value to be the value of the first datepicker.
Unfortunately we are getting an error because the values of datepickers are being instantiated at different times it seems and it throws an error cannot read getFullYear() of undefined....
Here is a line of code from the datepickers:

Comment: ```
<input type="month" ng-model="toDt" class="top-filter-controls" id="toDt" min="{{fromDt.getFullYear()+'-'+('0' + (fromDt.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)}}" ng-change="fetch(fromDt, toDt)" >
```

Comment: Seems simple enough. You'll need scope variables that represent the `ng-model` as value, min and max values for each control. Bind each of those simply like "{{frmMax}}" etc. In the `fetch()` method manipulate the $scope appropriately to set each of those properties with the dates you prefer. The point here is manipulating the data in your controller rather than trying to do that in the HTML template.